# How to append an element to an item with a specific class attribute in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append a

tag to a  tag that has a specific class. The append for the

is not happening.

This is what I'm trying to achieve - [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFoem.png)

And here is the code I am writing to achieve this - [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWwFm.png)

However, the generated html has no

tags at all. It does have all the  tags that I've appended to

Any thoughts on why I can't append the

to a  with a specific class?

Comment: please paste your code +expected outcome  here? images are not correct way to tell the problem

Comment: have you checked the jquery api ? http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 while(index>=0){
  var html = '<div class="'+array[index]+<p>'">Hello'+array[index]+'</p></div>';
        $body.append(html);
        index--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $body = $('body'); 
$body.html(''); 
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var index = array.length-1; 
while(index >= 0){ 
var value = array[index];
var $tweet = $('<div class = '+array[index]+'><p>' +array[index]+  ' is being shown</p></div>'); 
$tweet.appendTo($body);
index -= 1; 
} 

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of

```
 $('.' + array[index]).append($p);
```

used

```
 $tweet.append($p);
```

because class with div is not added in HTML and you are try to update it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var $body=$('body');
            $body.html('');
            var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
            var index = array.length - 1;
            while(index>=0)
            {
                var value = array[index];
                var $tweet = $('<div class="' + array[index] + '"></div>');
                var $p = $('<p></p>');
                $p.text(array[index] + ' is begin show');

                $tweet.append($p);
                $tweet.appendTo($body);
                index -= 1;

            }
        });
```